# Prove that a linear operator is indecomposable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$, and let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator. Prove that $T$ is indecomposable if and only if there is a unique maximal T-invariant proper subspace of $V$.

Definitions

A n×n matrix is decomposable if there exists a nonempty proper subset $I\subseteq{1,2,...,n}$ such that $a_{ij}$=0 whenever i$\in$I and j$\notin$I.

I only know the definition of maximal vector which is: A vector z such that the minimal polynomial of the operator T with respect to z = the minimal polynomial of the operator T, is called a maximal vector.

I tried using the definition of decomposable with respect to matrices, but I can't manipulate it to answer this question.

Comment: The definition of decomposable you have is weird. It describes block matrices up to permutation of the indices, which isn't invariant under matrix similarity.

Comment: Is it solvable with a different definition.